# Entity Configuration - One of the fields should be filled

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework code first approach in my application.

I have the below entity class..

```
 public class Filter : Entity
    {
        #region Property

        [Key]
        public int FilterID { get; set; }

        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

        public int CSAID { get; set; }
        public virtual UserLogin CSA { get; set; }

        public int VRAnalystID { get; set; }
        public virtual UserLogin VRAnalyst { get; set; }

        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public virtual UserLogin LoggedInUser { get; set; }

        public int QueueID { get; set; }
        public virtual Queue Queue { get; set; }

        #endregion Property

    }

 public class FilterConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Filter>
    {
        public FilterConfiguration()
        {
            this.HasKey(p => p.FilterID);
            this.Property(p => p.FilterID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).HasColumnName("FilterID");

            this.ToTable("Filter");
        }
    }
```

I have to make sure that either ClientID or CSAID or VRAnalystID should be filled for insert/update this entity.

How to set the entity configuration to achieve the same?

If this cannot be set in the entity configuration, what is the best practice to achieve the same functionality using Entity Framework code first approach?

Comment: If I understand correctly, at least one of the three foreign keys should be set before saving the entity?

Comment: I think it's not possible in EF. You should implement your own validation logic or use a SQL contraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement the IValidatableObject interface on your model class.  Then you can write your code in the method to verify one of them has a value.

```
  public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

            if (//some checks)
            {
                results.Add(new ValidationResult("Some Message",
                                                 new[] {"TheNameOfTheProperty"}));
            }

            return results;
        }
```